# Is there any onClose event in OpenFL?

Tags: haxe, nme

I am using a library which needs to be cleaned up at exit time (i.e. closing a socket so that it does not hang until some timeout) in an OpenFL 2.2.1 application.

However, I could not find any event which is called when I close the window with `Alt+F4` or the closing button of the window.

How can I detect that the application is terminating, in order to clean my resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question about `openfl-next`, there is the `lime.app.Application.onExit` event, which it inherits from `lime.app.Module`. An `Application` reference is stored in `openfl.display.Stage.application` instance field.

So, a multi-version variant of the function would be as following:

```
static function setExitHandler(func:Void->Void):Void {
    #if openfl_legacy
    openfl.Lib.current.stage.onQuit = function() {
        func();
        openfl.Lib.close();
    };
    #else
    openfl.Lib.current.stage.application.onExit.add(function(code) {
        func();
    });
    #end
}
```

And then you would just

```
setExitHandler(function() {
    trace("Quit!");
});
```

Comment: Was "next" at the time now lime 2.9.0?

Comment: Versions as of the time of writing were OpenFL 3.5.x/Lime 2.8.x. In the current versions, "next" is the default backend, while "legacy" is the older version of it that can be enabled via a flag (openfl_legacy) for compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Part of an answer would be to fallback to legacy OpenFL (with `-Dopenfl-legacy` or `<haxedef name="openfl-legacy" />`).

This trick forces the compiler into using the former API, which enables `Lib.stage.onQuit`.

```
public static function main():Void
{
    // …
    Lib.stage.onQuit = onClose;
    // …
}

private static function onClose()
{
    // …
    // Cleanup of opened resources
    // …
    Lib.close();
}
```

Be sure to call `Lib.close()` or your window won't be closeable any more!

However, this does not answer my question for the newer `openfl-next`.